# OPENCV waitKey() method return type

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to learn OPENCV for an image processing project using online tutorials.

The opencv documentation says that waitKey() returns an int. This is supposed to be the ASCII value of the key pressed. But most tutorials online use the following code which compiles and runs fine.

`if ( (char)27==waitKey(1) ) break;`

This suggests that waitKey returns a char and not an int.
Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cv::waitKey()` returns an `int`. The reason `char key = cv::waitKey(1)` works is due to implicit conversions in C++. In this case the return value of type `int` for `cv::waitKey()` is implicitely converted to `char` and then assigned to `key`. See [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) for reference. The following statements are equivalent:

```
char key = (char) cv::waitKey(30); // explicit cast
char key = cv::waitKey(30);        // implicit cast
```

In the case of `if ((char)27 == waitKey(1)) break;`, the output of `waitKey(1)` is probably implicitly converted to `char` and then compared to `esc` character (ASCII code 27). I would re-write it with explicit conversion to avoid ambiguity.

```
if ( (char)27 == (char) waitKey(1) ) break;
```

The way I see how it's often done in OpenCV sample cpp files:

```
char key = (char) cv::waitKey(30);   // explicit cast
if (key == 27) break;                // break if `esc' key was pressed. 
if (key == ' ') do_something();      // do_something() when space key is pressed
```

The following is also possible but the first approach is much cleaner:

```
int key = cv::waitKey(30) & 255; // key is an integer here
if (key == 27) break;            // break when `esc' key is pressed
```

Answer (score 1):

With Ubuntu 14.04, I had to use `cv::waitKey()%256` to obtain the correct ASCII code. 
You can print the result of `cv::waitKey()` to see if it works correct for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I have `opencv3.2` compiled for `Ubuntu 16.04`. `waitKey()` returns `int`, of which only `char` part is useful and the rest of the `int` seems to be a garbage. So, in video processing loop a line like this

```
if (cv::waitKey(10) > 0) break; // if key pressed then break
```

breaks almost for sure because even if you don't press a key a non-zero garbage will "press key" for you. But a line like this

```
if ((char)cv::waitKey(10) > 0) break; // if key pressed then break
```

works as intended and breaks only if a key was pressed. Similar logic is applied when you compare it with 27. The garbage in return value may be a bug in OpenCV indeed.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter as ASCII chars are between 0 and 127. So either cast results in the same practically.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, it uses some sort of 8-bit data type to represent keycodes. In a 8-bit singed integer datatype, -1 could be represented as eight 1s (1111 1111, complemental code). And in C++, integer datatype usually is 32-bit. So, eight 1s are interpreted as 255.