# How to detect keypress combination in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, ubuntu, keypress

I am having trouble detecting a combination of keys being pressed at the same time in an OpenCV program written in C++. I would like to be able to detect for example 'w' & 'a' at the same time.

I have tried cvWaitKey and cvWaitKeyEx, but both seem to return regular characters and either one key or another for keys pressed at the same time:

```
    //![check_keypress]
    char c = (char)waitKeyEx(1);

    std::cout << "c: " << c << " " << (int) c << "\n";
```

Is there a way to do this or can another library be utilized to do so? I have checked other posts such and I have not been able to find a solution.

Thanks

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411301/opencv-waitkey-method-return-type

Comment: How is this a duplicate? I need a combination of two separate keys at the same time, such as 'w' and 'a' or 'Shift' and A. That question does not even mention a combination of keys..

Comment: You detect keypress by waitKey and compare it with any character you want. The referenced answer describes this. It tells if you want do two different jobs get done by presseing two different keys. Chiefly, addresses the solution to your problem.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding the question I have - I want to know if there is a way to detect pressing two keys AT THE SAME TIME. Not one key is pressed then another is pressed.

Comment: If combination of two keys, e.g. Shift+a generates another character, say A, you can use the routine convention.

Comment: So unfortunately I cannot use just Shift, I am taking inputs from a keyboard and trying to create diagonals. Therefore if 'w' and 'a' keys are pressed at the same time I would be able to distinguish that from 'w' and 'a' pressed individually. Also 'Shift'+'a' doesn't register as 'A' in cvWaitKey, I just tested it, it registers as lowercase 'a'

Comment: The problem is the OS doesn't process two keypresses at the same time.  They will be perceived in a sequential manner. If you want to do something, you should look for a pattern.

Comment: I don't know of any software that accepts 2 keys being pressed at once, unless one of them is a *"modifier"* like `SHIFT`, `CTRL` or `ALT`. Do you?

Comment: That might not be possible using OpenCV only. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59924396/how-to-detect-when-a-key-is-released-in-opencv