# How to detect when a key is released in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, keyboard-events

If I run the following code

```
import cv2

cv2.namedWindow('Window')
while True:
    key = cv2.waitKey(50)
    print(key)
    if key == ord('q'):
        break
print('quit')
```

and press `i` (key code `105`) for a while, I get the output

```
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
105
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
105
105
105
105
105
105
105
105
105
105
-1
-1
```

The first occurrence of `105` is the time when I pressed `i` down. Even though I keep `i` pressed, I get `-1` nine times in a row. Then I constantly get `105` till I release `i`.

How do I know after the first occurrence of `105` if `i` is still pressed down or has been released when I get `-1` in both cases? Or in other words, how do you detect when a key is released in OpenCV?

Comment: opencv's user interface is very rudimentary. Use some "real" ui framework for additional functionalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV has a very basic properties for the interface. As [the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7) mentioned, It doesnt talk about released events:

> The function waitKey waits for a key event infinitely (when
>   ≤0 ) or for delay milliseconds, when it is positive. Since
>   the OS has a minimum time between switching threads, the function will
>   not wait exactly delay ms, it will wait at least delay ms, depending
>   on what else is running on your computer at that time. It returns the
>   code of the pressed key or -1 if no key was pressed before the
>   specified time had elapsed.

In your case, if you only use pressed event, it will work properly. Unfortunately you cant get released event using pressed event. You can use [MouseEvent types](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#gga927593befdddc7e7013602bca9b079b0ad3419100fc2d7688c6dbe3da030fbfd9) instead of keyEvent for release event or as *Micka* mentioned in the comment, it will better to use a ui based program.

Comment: Hi Mr/Sir @Yunus Temurlenk is it possible keyboard events ? without namedWindow as mentioned above example.

Comment: not with namedwindow but with a window. If you ask for the Opencv functionalities, the answer is no. Its only possible with a window. Otherwise search keyboard events for different languages(C++,Python etc.)

Comment: Yes in python keyword package it's helped me and thanks.