# Assigning cv2.waitKey() to a variable in python?

Tags: python, opencv

**I know you can use the 'waitKey()' function to wait for a while, but I saw a code block online for a video camera live recorder in which the function is assigned a variable to detect what key was pressed. What does this do?**

Here is the code with added comments (code without comment below this one)(not the same as the one from the internet but this script works too):

```
# Importing stuff to be able to install libraries
from subprocess import check_call 
from sys import executable

# Installing the required libraries
check_call([executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'numpy'])
check_call([executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'opencv-python'])

# Importing cv2
import cv2

#Creating a window and assigning the video capture to a variable
cv2.namedWindow('Video Feed')
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# The while loop to always record
while True:
    
    # Reading the video
    rval, frame = vc.read()
    
    # Showing the correct frame to the 'Video Feed' window
    cv2.imshow('Video Feed', frame)
    
    # Assigning the function waitKey() to the variable 'key'
    # This is what I do not understand, why does it work and
    # why is can't I find any record on the internet of the function being able to do this?
    key = cv2.waitKey(20)

    # Checking if the variable key is 27
    # This is a true statement when you press 'ESC'
    # Where can I find the table for what numbers correspond to what keys?
    # Does this mean that the function outputs a number when assigned to a variable?
    if key == 27:
        
        # Exiting loop
        break

# Closing stuff
vc.release()
cv2.destroyWindow('Video Feed')
```

Code without comments because I can't read with that many comments:

```
from subprocess import check_call
from sys import executable
    
check_call([executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'numpy'])
check_call([executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'opencv-python'])

import cv2

cv2.namedWindow('Video Feed')
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    
    rval, frame = vc.read()
    cv2.imshow('Video Feed', frame)
    
    key = cv2.waitKey(20)
    if key == 27:
        break

vc.release()
cv2.destroyWindow('Video Feed')
```

Basically, where do I find documentation on this way of using the function, and how can I use it for other keyboard presses?

Comment: you can find the docs at https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/ -- you are expected to google before asking. please take the [tour], then review [ask] and [help/on-topic]

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I did google, I googled 7 different things regarding the subject where I opened about 3 pages each search which all said that waitKey delays the time before a window closes.

Comment: hmmmm well the docs do say it, but not very clearly. *"It returns the code of the pressed key"* perhaps the docs should spend an extra sentence or two on that

Comment: Important to highlight that waitKey(x) does not guarantee to wait x, because it will finish its waiting once a key is pressed. So basically what it does is: Waiting until a key is pressed OR until x time exceeded (if x > 0). If a key was pressed, the key code is returned. If no key was pressed -1 (?) is returned. When there is no opencv window, waitKey does nothing. During waitKey time, the window rendering from imshow calls will be processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waitkey returns the ASCII code for the key pressed on the keyboard. In the above case, escape = 27, so the loop will exit when escape is pressed.

I'm not 100% sure how it works in python, but you should be able to say something like:

```
if 'k' == cv2.waitKey(1):
    # some code here after k key pressed
```

Here is a similar question, where it is explained for c++: [OPENCV waitKey() method return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411301/opencv-waitkey-method-return-type)

And here is the opencv docs: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7

And here is the ASCII table:
https://www.asciitable.com/